# How can I do multiple concurrent insert transactions against postgres without causing a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, database-deadlocks

I have a large dump file that I am processing in parallel and inserting into a postgres 9.4.5 database. There are ~10 processes that all are starting a transaction, inserting ~X000 objects, and then committing, repeating until their chunk of the file is done. **Except they never finish because the database locks up.**

The dump contains 5 million or so objects, each object representing an album. An object has a title, a release date, a list of artists, a list of track names etc. I have a release table for each one of these (who's primary key comes from the object in the dump) and then join tables with their own primary keys for things like release_artist, release_track.

The tables look like this:

```
Table: mdc_releases
  Column   |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id        | integer                  | not null  | plain    |              | 
 title     | text                     |           | extended |              | 
 released  | timestamp with time zone |           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "mdc_releases_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

Table: mdc_release_artists
   Column   |  Type   |                            Modifiers                             | Storage | Stats target | Description 
------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer | not null default nextval('mdc_release_artists_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 release_id | integer |                                                                  | plain   |              | 
 artist_id  | integer |                                                                  | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "mdc_release_artists_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

and inserting an object looks like this:

```
insert into release(...) values(...) returning id;  // refer to id below as $ID
insert into release_meta(release_id, ...) values ($ID, ...);
insert into release_artists(release_id, ...) values ($ID, ...), ($ID, ...), ...;
insert into release_tracks(release_id, ...) values ($ID, ...), ($ID, ...), ...;
```

So the transactions look like BEGIN, the above snippet 5000 times, COMMIT. I've done some googling on this and I'm not sure why what look to me like independent inserts are causing deadlocks.

This is what select * from pg_stat_activity shows:

```
|         state_change          | waiting |        state        | backend_xid | backend_xmin |              query              
+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------------
| 2016-01-04 18:42:35.542629-08 | f       | active              |             |      2597876 | select * from pg_stat_activity;
| 2016-01-04 07:36:06.730736-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:37:36.066837-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:37:36.314909-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:37:49.491939-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:36:04.865133-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:38:39.344163-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:36:48.400621-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:34:37.802813-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:37:24.615981-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:37:10.887804-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
| 2016-01-04 07:37:44.200148-08 | f       | idle in transaction |             |              | BEGIN
```

Comment: Is the `id` for `releases` being inserted, or is it being auto-generated?  If the former then you can insert the same value via `insert into release_meta` etc rather than having the subsequent inserts depend on the initial insert; if the latter then I think you need to add an autoincrement default to your `releases:id` column